# Python Dictionary - Key Assignment by iterations

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have created the following dictionary:

```
workers = ['Thomas', 'Jack',  'Charles', 'Peter']

GrpList = {('Task {1}'.format for i in range(1,3)): workers}
```

And the output is:

```
{<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001AF99B861C8>: ['Thomas','Jack','Charles','Peter']}
```

How can I modify my codes (in a single line) so that the result can be:

```
{'Task 1': ['Thomas','Jack','Charles','Peter'],
 'Task 2': ['Thomas','Jack','Charles','Peter'],
 'Task 3': ['Thomas','Jack','Charles','Peter']}

instead of showing a generator expression in the dictionary keys.
```

Comment: Note that even if this succeeds all of your values will refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your dictionary comprehension, do this:

```
workers = ['Thomas', 'Jack', 'Charles', 'Peter']

GrpList = {f'Task {i}': workers for i in range(1, 4)}

print(GrpList)
```

The idea is to use `range` to generate the keys, the values are all the same. As an alternative you could use [dict.fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
GrpList = dict.fromkeys((f'Task {i}' for i in range(1, 4)), workers)
```

**Output**

```
{'Task 1': ['Thomas', 'Jack', 'Charles', 'Peter'], 'Task 2': ['Thomas', 'Jack', 'Charles', 'Peter'], 'Task 3': ['Thomas', 'Jack', 'Charles', 'Peter']}
```

**Observations**

1) All the keys refer to the same list, if you want the keys to refer to equal values, but not the same, do this instead:

```
GrpList = {f'Task {i}': workers[:] for i in range(1, 4)}
```

2) The name `GrpList`, suggest a list but the actual value is a dictionary, perhaps using another name, such as `GrpDict`, would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the argument to `format`:

```
GrpList = {'Task {}'.format(i) : workers for i in range(1,4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you can achieve your purpose using this code:

`grp_list = {"Task {}".format(i+1): workers for i in range(0, len(workers))}`